# How can i get dynamicallly created control on button click event in my application page

Tags: application-pages

I am creating controls base on the number of rows in my data table.
Here is my code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dataTable1.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        TableRow tr = new TableRow();

                        TableCell td1 = new TableCell();
                        TableCell td2 = new TableCell();
                        td1.Style.Add("width", "200px");

                        Label lblSite = new Label();
                        lblSite.ID = "lblSite";
                        lblSite.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Title"].ToString();


                        TextBox txtComment = new TextBox();
                        txtComment.ID = "txtComment";
                        txtComment.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;

                        td1.Controls.Add(lblSite);
                        td2.Controls.Add(txtComment);

                        tr.Cells.Add(td1);
                        tr.Cells.Add(td2);

                        Table1.Rows.Add(tr);
                        Table1.EnableViewState = true;
                        ViewState["Table1"] = true;
                    }
```

Now i want to get both the control in button click event and their text one by one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically created controls will not be part of the page view state and hence during PostBack those controls will get lost. To avoid this, you should handle `Page_Load` event and recreate those controls dynamically.

Below is a pseudo code you can follow

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label l = new Label();
    l.ID = "lblTest";
    l.Text = "Some Text";

    Page.Controls.Add(l);
}
```

Now in button click event you can find the control

```
Label l = Page.FindControl("lblTest");
```